# Python for loops program with square

Tags: python, for-loop

how do i create a program (Python for loops)that will ask the user for a number and then print out a list of number from 1 to the number entered and the square of the number. For example, if the user entered '3' then the program would output:
1 squared is 1.
2 squared is 4.
3 squared is 9.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Where's your code?  See [ask].  Take the [Tour].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple. You should try it yourself first. I am just giving you some code.

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print i, i*i
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your request correctly:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    print("%s² = %s"%(i,i**2))
```

& without zero:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print("%s² = %s"%(i,i**2))
```